# Using getThreads code not working in GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

I run this code and it does nothing. No errors, no output. Any help would be appreciated!

I've tried changing everything...the range, name of the sheet, appendRow vs. setValues. I've added 0,10 for start and max of threads, removed the first for loop...nothing has worked so far.

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("NewEmails"); 
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,25,25);


  //.appendRow("this function works a little");

  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,10); // get first thread in inbox
  //var message = thread.getMessages()[0]; // get first message

  //var threads = label.getThreads();

 for (var i=0; i<10; i++) //threads.length
  {
    var messages = threads.getMessages();

    for (var j=0; j<10; j++) //messages.length
    {

      var dat = messages[j].getDate();
      var sndr = messages[j].getFrom();
      var rcpnt = messages[j].getTo();
      var sub = messages[j].getSubject();
      var msg = messages[j].getBody();

      var target = [dat,sndr,rcpnt,msg, sub, dat];

      sheet.getRange(1,1,25,25).setValues(target);

      //.appendRow([dat,sndr,rcpnt,msg, sub, dat]); DOES NOT WORK FOR SOME REASON BUT IS PREFERED METHOD
    }
      //threads[i].removeLabel(label);
  }
}
```

Comment: The target must be a 2D array.  `setValues()` takes a 2D array.  Each inner array represents a row.  Each element of each inner array represents an individual cell.  `var outerArray = []; outerArray.push(target); sheet.getRange(1,1,outerArray.length,target.length).setValues(outerArray);` If you are not familiar with troubleshooting tools, read the [troubleshooting guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting)

Comment: Yes, I realized setValues() and setValue() are a big difference. These two can be used with a range. appendRow() must be used at the sheet level.

Answer (score 1):

I never played around with this before but I finally got this to work.

```
function onOpen()
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Tools')
    .addItem('Get My Messages', 'MyMessages')
    .addToUi();
}

function MyMessages()
{  
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  var s = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) 
  {
    var msg = threads[i].getMessages();
    for(var j = 0; j < msg.length;j++)
    {
      s += 'Message' + j+1 + '<br />';
      s += msg[j].getFrom() + '<br />';
      s += msg[j].getBody() + '<br />';

    }

  }
  dispStatus('My Messages', s , 800 , 400);  
}

function dispStatus(title,html,width,height)
{
  var title = typeof(title) !== 'undefined' ? title : 'No Title Provided';
  var width = typeof(width) !== 'undefined' ? width : 800;
  var height = typeof(height) !== 'undefined' ? height : 400;
  var html = typeof(html) !== 'undefined' ? html : '<p>No html provided.</p>';
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
     .createHtmlOutput(html)
     .setWidth(width)
     .setHeight(height);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlOutput, title);
}
```

I didn't try to put it in the spreadsheet but I suppose that is left as an exercise for the reader.  But remember that when you using setValues into a range, the size of the source has to equal the size of the destination and it doesn't appear to me that they do.

```
var target = [dat,sndr,rcpnt,msg, sub, dat];
sheet.getRange(1,1,25,25).setValues(target);
```

target is 1 row by 5 columns and your destination is 25 x 25 so I'm guessing that won't fly.  The other advantage of displaying them in an html dialog is that they are already in html format.

Comment: OMG! you are the best. I've been working with a similar script and just got the posting to spreadsheet figured out but not the rest. Let me test this script but I believe you even solved a few other problems!!!

Comment: Side question: Since you seem to know more about creating user interfaces...do you know if I convert my scripts into a user interface like this if they will run faster as opposed to using google sheets?

Comment: I don't really know.  But my guess is that if you taking maximum advantage of clientside (html dialogs and side bars)  and maximal advantage on the server side then I'd guess the server will always win.  Having said that I have found that setting values in individual spreadsheets is very time consuming as opposed to using setValues and giving it an array.  This is the first time I've ever messed the GmailApp so I guess the best answer for me is that don't know.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'm no expert but I was expecting something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that helped this code was I realized setValues() and setValue() are a big difference. These two can be used with a range. appendRow() must be used at the sheet level.

you can say: sheet.appendRow() but not range.appendRow(). Hope this helps someone.